# Samba: Cannot see Shared folders

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

i'm trying to connect my laptop to pc thorugh LAN (both are ubuntu) because i need to grab some data there. the problem is when i browse network section in nautilus i cannot see folder list that i already set on that desktop, but instead all i see is my own shares folder in this laptop. is it because my laptop and desktop shares the same name ' james ' or?

im looking forward for your answers and help... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop and desktop do indeed need a different name if you want to access shares through SMB.